# Installing CDT into Eclipse with P2 director gives "The target server failed to respond"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, p2

I download the 2020-03 Eclipse Platform Runtime Binary (v4.15 from eclipse-platform-4.15-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz), then invoke the p2 director to install CDT package, but I'm always getting multiple caught exceptions of http://download.eclipse.org not responding (http/https switch doesn't have effect on this).

```
./eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -profile SDKProfile -noSplash -roaming -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03,http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03/202003181000/,http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.15/,http://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest,http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/9.11 -installIU org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group/9.11.0.202003091030
```

I tried it with Oracle JRE 8 and with Oracle JDK 14, I tried it on Debian and RHEL machines, tried different network connection (3 different IPS locations), removed all other plugins I install to nail it down to the CDT plugin. I do not know why or what is causing it, and searching for this problems shows to people that ISP fixed or some similar solution. While mine is consistent for about a year. I always eventually finishes, but it will will print out multiple messages:

```
Installing org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 9.11.0.202003091030.
Apr 22, 2020 1:44:29 P.M. org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://download.eclipse.org:80: The target server failed to respond
Apr 22, 2020 1:44:29 P.M. org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://download.eclipse.org:80
Apr 22, 2020 1:44:36 P.M. org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://download.eclipse.org:80: The target server failed to respond
Apr 22, 2020 1:44:36 P.M. org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://download.eclipse.org:80
Operation completed in 44091 ms.
```

Using the HTTPS repositories has similar output:

```
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://download.eclipse.org:443: The target server failed to respond
Apr 22, 2020 4:02:50 P.M. org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://download.eclipse.org:443
Operation completed in 46934 ms.
```

It's not critical as it eventually completes and the end result works, but I would like to understand it better what is happening, what has effect on this behaviour. When I shrink the list of repositories to these two, it will still install, but the messages will be present:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03,http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/9.11
```

Is there maybe a resource/documentation which probably I missed and is explaining more in the detail what is happening and why?

Comment: What is `./eclipse` for an Eclipse version? Please show everything with HTTPS instead of with HTTP even if you convinced this has no effect.

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean, the eclipse is from the Platform Runtime Binary 2020-03, specifically taken from this file eclipse-platform-4.15-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz and eclipse.buildId=4.15.0.I20200305-0155. I was using the HTTPS repositories for about half year or more before switching to HTTP today just to see if anything has effect on it. Plus I was double checking a regular interactive Eclipse CDT installation and that is using HTTP for all repositories. I will update the question with the HTTPs  output (which is almost the same).

Comment: I see. Looks like [Eclipse bug 560808](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=560808).

Comment: Thank you it does, when I started experiencing this issue last year this bug was not there yet. You would reckon I should just wait until the timeout is changed and ignore the warnings in the meantime?

Comment: Yes, if I understand it correctly, these messages can be seen as noise you can ignore. You might add yourself to the CC list of this bug to be kept updated.

Comment: thanks, will do that